# Is there a map() equivalent for PDL without doing pdl( map {} unpdl)?

Tags: perl, pdl

I would like to do something like this to call myfunc() on each element *in-place* on an existing [PDL](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL):

```perl
$pdl = pdl [1,2,3];
$pdl = pdl [ map { myfunc($_) } @{ unpdl($pdl) } ];
```

I've searched through the documentation, but nothing yet:

Is there a way to visit each element of a PDL and run something on the element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `broadcast_define` (`thread_define` in older versions) for this:

```perl
use PDL;

broadcast_define('square(a();[o]b())', over { $_[1] .= $_[0] ** 2 });

my $pdl = pdl [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
square($pdl, (my $out = null));
print($out); # $out is pdl [[1,4,9], [16,25,36]]
```

this is slower than using native ops (`$pdl**2` gets the same result in this case, and many more complicated things are possible by composing native ops), or [PDL::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::PP), in which you write your function in C, but it is faster than `unpdl`/`map`/`pdl`.

You have to look at the PDL::PP docs for explanations of the signature like `(a();[o]b())`, but this is the simple case: the function has a scalar input and a scalar output, and can be broadcast to any number of dimensions.

I can't seem to get `broadcast_define`d functions to return a value when the output argument is omitted (e.g. `my $out = square($pdl)`), but you can do in-place modification with `square($pdl, $pdl)`.

Comment: +1 for a great answer. The return value thing is showing a shortcoming of `broadcast_define`; it doesn't handle varargs like the generated XS for "real" PP operations. If you can show some inputs and expected varargs-ish output, then that can form a test for such functionality (though the ideal is a pull-request with that and a fix ;-)