# Does Perl PDL have an equivalent of Math::Round::nearest()?

Tags: perl, pdl

Does [PDL](https://metacpan.org/dist/PDL) already have a way to apply a "rounding" to the vector elements by some precision in the way that [Math::Round::nearest()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Round) does?  I've looked through the [PDL::Math](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::Math) documentation but didn't see a good candidate option.

[I could unpdl/re-pdl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72589417/14055985) but that seems like too much overhead.

Is there already a vectorized way to do this?

I tried something like this:

```perl
$pdl = pdl [4.45, 5.55, 45];
$n = pdl [.1, .3, 10];
print rint($pdl/$n)*$n
[4.4 5.4 40]
```

but as as you can see it doesn't quite work because it should round up to the nearest precision.  This would be the "correct" output:

```perl
[4.5 5.6 50]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [PDL::Math's `rint` documentation](https://metacpan.org/release/ETJ/PDL-2.080/view/GENERATED/PDL/Math.pm#rint), `rint` uses "round half to even" (aka "banker's rounding").  They then go on to explain that to always round half up (regardless of sign, so 4.5 to 5.0 and -4.5 to -4.0), use `floor($x+0.5)`, and to round half away from zero (so 4.5 to 5.0 and -4.5 to -5.0), use `ceil(abs($x)+0.5)*($x<=>0)`

I ran the following in the `perldl` shell, adding some extra example numbers:

```perl
pdl> p $pdl = pdl [5.55, 45, 55, -45, -55, 4.45, 4.55, -4.45, -4.55]
[5.55 45 55 -45 -55 4.45 4.55 -4.45 -4.55]

pdl> p $n = pdl [.3, 10, 10, 10, 10, .1, .1, .1, .1]
[0.3 10 10 10 10 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1]

pdl> p "bankers rounding: " => rint($pdl/$n)*$n
bankers rounding:  [5.4 40 60 -40 -60 4.4 4.5 -4.4 -4.5]

pdl> p "round half up:    " => floor($pdl/$n+0.5)*$n
round half up:     [5.7 50 60 -40 -50 4.5 4.5 -4.4 -4.5]

pdl> p "round half away:  " => ceil(abs($pdl/$n)+0.5)*(($pdl/$n)<=>0)*$n
round half away:   [5.7 50 60 -50 -60 4.5 4.6 -4.5 -4.6]
```

Aside: On your "correct" output, I don't see how 5.55 rounded by 0.3 should be 5.6, as 5.6 is not a multiple of 0.3.  The nearest multiple of 0.3 above 5.55 is 5.7.

**Update**: Looking at [Math::Round::nearest()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Round#nearest-TARGET,-LIST), it looks like it rounds toward infinity, so the "round half away" example would be what matches the behavior of "equivalent to Math::Round::nearest()"

Answer (score 2):

Such a thing could be added, but would need to be specified a bit more clearly; what would it do with negative numbers? And how would it differ from `floor` / `ceil` / `rint`?

Comment: I was considering looking at the `nearest()` implementation and see if it can be done as a vector.  Basically whatever nearest() does is what I'm trying to do.  Right now I deconstruct the pdl, run nearest, and put it back together again.

Comment: That's not a clear answer to the question posed above ;-)