# Does Perl PDL have a way to clamp a vector by min/max values given in another vector without iterating?

Tags: perl, pdl

Does [PDL](https://metacpan.org/dist/PDL) already have a way to "clamp" vector elements to min/max values given in another vector?  I've looked through the [PDL::Math](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::Math) documentation but didn't see a good candidate option.

[I could unpdl/re-pdl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72589417/14055985) but that seems like too much overhead.

Is there already a vectorized way to do this?

I tried something like this:

```perl
$pdl = pdl [4.45, 5.55, 45];
$max = pdl [2   , 3,    50];
print ( (($max <=> $pdl) > 0)*$pdl + (($max <=> $pdl) < 0)*$max ) 
[2 3 45]
```

which seems to work, but what a crazy expression.  Is there a built-in for this?

Comment: Your print could be simplified to ` ($max > $pdl) *$pdl + ($max <= $pdl)*$max`

Comment: @clamp, did you change your username just to answer this question about clamping values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`PDL::Primitive::hclip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::Primitive#hclip) is for this:

```
pdl> $pdl = pdl [4.45, 5.55, 45];
pdl> $max = pdl [2   , 3,    50];
pdl> p $pdl->hclip($max)
[2 3 45]
```